# Filling one form from another does not get all values from the second form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two form:
the first one "FrmAddRecordOfNonComplianceQHSE" has in load event this code

```
        private async void FrmAddRecordOfNonComplianceQHSE_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KeyPreview = true;
        txtCreationDate.EditValue = DateTime.Today;

        DataTable DDt = await qhse.GetLastQHSEOrderNumberRecordOfNonCompliance().ConfigureAwait(true);
        string RatingNumber = DDt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        txtOrderNumber.Text = RatingNumber;

        cmbDetecteurStructure.Properties.DataSource = await qhse.GetEmployeesByDepartmentID(Program.FK_Department).ConfigureAwait(true);
        cmbDetecteurStructure.Properties.DisplayMember = "Nom et Prénom";
        cmbDetecteurStructure.Properties.ValueMember = "Matricule";

        cmbRelevantStructure.Properties.DataSource = await qhse.Get_Department().ConfigureAwait(true);
        cmbRelevantStructure.Properties.DisplayMember = "Département";
        cmbRelevantStructure.Properties.ValueMember = "ID_Department";
    }
```

and I have this code also

```
    private void cmbRelevantStructure_Closed(object sender, ClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { cmbRelevantEmployee.EditValue = null; }));
    }

    private async void cmbRelevantEmployee_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cmbRelevantEmployee.Properties.DataSource = await qhse.GetManagerByDepartmentID(Convert.ToInt32(cmbRelevantStructure.EditValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)).ConfigureAwait(true);
            cmbRelevantEmployee.Properties.DisplayMember = "Nom et Prénom";
            cmbRelevantEmployee.Properties.ValueMember = "Matricule";
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

and about the second form "FrmRecordOfNonComplianceQHSE" I have this code

```
FrmAddRecordOfNonComplianceQHSE frmQHSE = new FrmAddRecordOfNonComplianceQHSE();
```

and on DoubleClick of gridView1 I have this code

```
         private async void gridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                      
                    //frmQHSE.cmbDetecteurStructure.Properties.DataSource = null;
                    frmQHSE.cmbDetecteurStructure.EditValue = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "FKDetecteur");
                    frmQHSE.txtCreationDate.EditValue = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "CreationDate");
                    frmQHSE.txtOrderNumber.Text = string.Empty;
                    frmQHSE.txtOrderNumber.Text = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "OrderNumber").ToString();
                    frmQHSE.cmbRelevantStructure.EditValue = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "RelevantDepartment");
                    frmQHSE.cmbRelevantEmployee.Enter += new EventHandler(cmbRelevantEmployee_Enter);
                    frmQHSE.cmbRelevantEmployee.EditValue = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "FKRelevant");

                    if (frmQHSE == null || frmQHSE.IsDisposed)
                        frmQHSE = new FrmAddRecordOfNonComplianceQHSE();
                    frmQHSE.ShowDialog();
    }
```

and I have this code also

```
private async void cmbRelevantEmployee_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            frmQHSE.cmbRelevantEmployee.Properties.DataSource = await qhse.GetManagerByDepartmentID(Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "RelevantDepartment"), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)).ConfigureAwait(true);
            frmQHSE.cmbRelevantEmployee.Properties.DisplayMember = "Nom et Prénom";
            frmQHSE.cmbRelevantEmployee.Properties.ValueMember = "Matricule";
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Now when I DoubleClick on gridView1 row the first form open but the controls get the values from the load event of that form not the values of gridView1 of my second form.
How can solve this problem ?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you followed your code, to see when the `Load` event of the first Form is called? When you `new` it or when you `Show()` it? The `async` call in the `Load` event is not exactly useful. `ConfigureAwait(true)` is the default.

Comment: it is load after frmQHSE.ShowDialog(); after the load event complete the from1 show up

Comment: Yes. The `Load` event is raised only when you `Show()` a Form, not when you create a new instance. If you set some properties right after you have created the instance, these properties may be overwritten by what's in the `Load()` handler.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use data binding and assign an object to `DataSource` **or** assign values to the controls, but do not mix both approaches.

I assume that `GetManagerByDepartmentID` now returns a `DataTable` or something like this, since you have display member names with spaces. Create data classes instead. This makes it easier to manipulate the data. Something like this

```
public class Employee
{
    public string NomPrénom { get; set; }
    public int Matricule { get; set; }
    public string Département { get; set; }
    public int ID_Department { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now, you can let `GetManagerByDepartmentID` return an `Employee` object. Your form binds to an `Employee` object and your grid can bind to an `Employee` object. Or at least you can create and fill such an object manually and assign it to the `DataSource` of the first form.

```
private async void gridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                      
    var emp = new Employee {
        FKDetecteur = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "FKDetecteur"),
        CreationDate = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "CreationDate"),
        OrderNumber gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "OrderNumber").ToString(),
        ....
     };
     frmQHSE.EmployeeBindingSource.DataSource = emp;
     frmQHSE.ShowDialog();
}
```

Use `BindingSource`es in conjunction with object data sources on your from. This allows you to set `DisplayMember`s and `ValueMember`s in the forms designer.

Comment: Thank you for your great help